# using uwsgi --emperor cannot create sock file

Tags: python, deployment, uwsgi

Here is my nginx config

```
upstream app {
    server unix:///tmp/rate.sock;
}
```

and my uwsgi config

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/dev/rate/rate
module          = docrate.wsgi
home            = /home/ubuntu/dev/rate
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /tmp/rate.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum = true
```

If I use `uwsgi --ini rate_uwsgi.ini` to start, it's fine.
But if I use emperor, the sock file isn't created.

`uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi.d --uid www-data --gid www-data`

I just wanna figure it out. And my uwsgi version is `1.9.11`.

Comment: Can you paste the exception in here? If you've since closed your shell, try to start the emperor again from your shell and paste the error output in here. It's possible that you created the socket file with `sudo` before trying to start this (`www-data` can't access at that point), or something to that effect.

Comment: Also (unrelated), how many threads does your hardware come with (number of physical cores * number of threads each core has built in)? This number should be used to help determine the number of `processes` in your uWSGI ini. If you have a dual core processor with 2 threads per core, your hardware is really optimized to act as if it has 4 cores (sort of), and you won't gain much (maybe lose some) by having 10 processes. This changes, if your application is very I/O bound.

Comment: @orokusaki if i goto `/etc/uwsgi.d` and run `uwsgi --ini rate_uwsgi.ini`

Comment: @orokusaki I get this [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from rate_uwsgi.ini
open("rate_uwsgi.ini"): Too many levels of symbolic links [core/io.c line 431]

Comment: It sounds like you have a loop (e.g., a sym link from A that points to B which points to C which points back to A). Use `ls -l` in a directory to see sym links in that directory (look for the arrow from name to destination in the output).

Comment: @orokusaki i just have one link

Comment: @orokusaki thank you for your help, after remove the copy, I relink the file, and it works

Comment: @luther - no prob. Since your question was answered in chat, you can delete the question, if you want.